# Adding Apache POI 3.12 to Eclipse

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I know this Question has been asked before but I can't do it! It's my first try ever to import something.

I followed these instructions http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi/apache_poi_environment.htm

but I just get 
"XSSFWorkBook cannot be resolved to a type"

Also Code Completion don't know any org.apache Classes.

Is it because the dom4j-1.6.1.jar file is missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to add that jar to check if it fixes the issue?

Comment: Well it's not in the POI zip file so from where should I download it? oh okay i found it here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/d/dom4j.htm but I also found in the change log here https://poi.apache.org/changes.html this "Switch from dom4j to JAXP" So I guess I don't need it?

Comment: Which jars did you add to your Eclipse classpath? And what code are you trying to write which isn't workign?

Comment: I added 
poi-3.12-20150511.jar; poi-ooxml-3.12-20150511.jar; poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12-20150511.jar; ooxml-lib\xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar and i just tried some samplecode from here (it was the create blank workbook) http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi/apache_poi_workbooks.htm